# Is Azure Patch Orchestration (POA) blocked on Cluster "Warning" or only "Error"

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Node restarts have ripple effects in one of our SF Apps. It takes our service a bit of time to recover after a reboot. We have a watchdog that monitors this and will set the Cluster Health to "Warning" while it is recovering (and to "Error" if recovery fails).  Based on this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-patch-orchestration-application

> Cluster-aware patching and health integration. While POA is applying
> updates, it monitors the health of the cluster nodes. Cluster nodes
> are updated one node at a time or one update domain at a time. If the
> health of the cluster goes down because of the patching process,
> patching is stopped to prevent aggravating the problem.

We assumed that POA would be blocked until the cluster is "OK." We are seeing that this is not the case and that patching continues with the health in "Warning." This causes multiple recoveries to happen at same time in our service and brings us down.

I could set the health to Error I assume, but I have alerting on that and Error will trigger a 24x7 on call response (where Warning is business hours).

Should POA be getting blocked in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code on https://github.com/microsoft/Service-Fabric-POA,it appears as though it does only block on Error

```
/// <summary>
/// Post the cluster patching status as events on CoordinatorService
/// </summary>
public async Task PostClusterPatchingStatus(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        NodeList nodeList = await this.fabricClient.QueryManager.GetNodeListAsync(null, null, this.DefaultTimeoutForOperation, cancellationToken);
        IList<RepairTask> claimedTaskList = await this.GetClaimedRepairTasks(nodeList, cancellationToken);
        RepairTaskList processingTaskList = await this.GetRepairTasksUnderProcessing(cancellationToken);
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        if (claimedTaskList.Any())
        {
            if (!processingTaskList.Any())
            {
                // This means that repair tasks are not getting approved.
                ClusterHealth clusterHealth = await this.fabricClient.HealthManager.GetClusterHealthAsync();
                if (clusterHealth.AggregatedHealthState == HealthState.Error)
                { 
                    // Reset Count
                    postUpdateCount = 0;
                    string warningDescription = " Cluster is currently unhealthy. Nodes are currently not getting patched by Patch Orchestration Application. Please ensure the cluster becomes healthy for patching to continue.";
                    await PostWarningOnCoordinatorService(warningDescription, 1);
                }
                else
                {
```